# GroupConnect Add LINE Account Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Can't find an option to add a LINE account with GroupConnect in Marketing Cloud.

The account dropdown in blank.  How to add account?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Currently going through this myself. To activate Line, you'll have to go through your Account Exec. Seems that it is something that requires backend configuration. Updates when we get it set up.

Comment: Can GroupConnect be used in a journey to send LINE messages? @Doug

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but will confirm once our AE gets it set up

Comment: have you got an update whether LINE can be used within Journey? @Doug

Comment: LINE with journey builder feature is being released in May 2019.  Here's the article 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_april_2019_gc_line_in_content_and_journey_builder.htm&type=5

Comment: Yep:) but watch out for the details. You can't set the contact key for line to match your CRM so that means journeys but only single channel for now

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a provider in Line app and that will be visible here under the account.
Let me know u need any more details on this.